# Wordpress wp-admin Page

Tags: wp-admin

I just installed a wordpress from my c panel, when i tried login to wp-admin it shows an unknown page instead of wp-admin.
please somebody can help ??[image]

Comment: You should contact your web host. They have routed your domain to some ad page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the URLs in the wp-options table are incorrect.

If he can get to `www.example.com` , but not `www.example.com/wp-admin` , then the routing by the host is probably correct.

Check the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering whether you bought the domain from hostgator but your hosting elsewhere.  It isn't only your wp-admin page that is wrong, the entire site is showing that page.

The nameservers are pointing to hostgator, but it looks like that isn't where your site is.  Check that the nameservers are correct.